# Casimir operators and irreducible representations

Tags: group-theory

I found the following reading a paper (http://www.vsi.cs.uni-frankfurt.de/download/KrajsekVisapp06.pdf, pg 4 first column). The statement is for for compact groups:

if "a Casimir operator
has the symmetry of the group G, i.e. there exists
no operation which does not belong to the group and
under which the Casimir operator is invariant, then
its eigenfunctions are basis functions of irreducible
representation (Wigner, 1959).

I cannot figure out where to find this result in the Wigner book.
Is this a well konw fact? Someone can help?

Thanks!!!

Fabio

Comment: I think that [it boils down to Schur's lemma of representation theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2535145/8157).